# trigonometry limit finding using squeeze thereom didn't work out

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2^x}-3x+2, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}$$
and I want to find the $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}{\frac{\sin(f(x))}{x}}.$$
I have that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}{f(x)}=+\infty,$$ so I am thinking of using the squeeze theorem to find $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}{\frac{\sin(f(x))}{x}},$$ but this wasn't work for me. Any ideas? (I don't want to use de L'Hospital Rule)

Comment: Hint: $\sin$ is bounded.

Comment: Start with $-1 \leq \sin(f(x)) \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes simply squeeze theorem noting that

$$\left|\frac{\sin(f(x))}{x}\right| \le \left|\frac{1}{x}\right|$$

and this directly leads to $0$.